# Why doesn't my border change to the specified color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The function below is to update the score counter and also add a glow effect to the button clicked but instead of the new color added the background color overrides. i.e instead of the intended gray, the blue(background color) covers the borders.

JS code:

```
function updateScore(resultType, userChoice){
    if(resultType === "tie"){
        userScore = userScore + 1;
        userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
        computerScore = computerScore + 1;
        computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
        document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('gray-glow');
        setTimeout(() => document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('gray-glow'), 500);
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice" id="rock">
            <img src="assets/rock.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="paper">
            <img src="assets/paper.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="scissors">
            <img src="assets/scissors.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.gray-glow{
    border: 4px gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(61, 68, 70);
}
```

Comment: border: 4px solid gray; you are missing solid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the solid part of the border css

```css
.gray-glow{
    border: 4px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(61, 68, 70);
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
        <div class="choice gray-glow" id="rock">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="paper">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="scissors">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks  a ton man.I'd been going crazy shifting the code below and above the body. Thanks for helping me i can finally carry on with my day lol. Hope You have a good day too :D

Comment: Your welcome :) glad to be a help

Comment: @HypNyx get an ide that highlights syntax errors, for example intellij idea community is even free - even a simple code editor will do it

Comment: @chrispbacon i use visual code. i dont believe that missing the 'solid' was a syntax error. the code ran but didnt do what i intended. if you could suggest other editors it would be of great help :)

Comment: What you had was invalid code, an editor should highlight that. You can also write gibberish and whatnot in your css and it will still "run" - whatever that means for you.

Comment: @chrispbacon i didnt know that and will keep it in mind for future. Thanks for tips.